# How to preserver file attributes with universal packages in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a few tools that I would like to use during a build. For Azure DevOps I tried putting them in a Universal Package. This works great for Windows but on Linux and Mac the file attributes are not preserved, specifically the execution bit. Is there some way to preserve the attributes with a Universal Package, or is there another tactic I need to take to use tools during a build?

I need something that is not done by a pipeline task because it needs to happen on developer's boxes as well. Pulling just about any sort of repository or package is viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to preserver file attributes with universal packages in Azure DevOps?

I am afraid there is no such way to preserver file attributes with universal packages in Azure DevOps.

It is precisely because of the non-preserving properties of universal packages that it may be used to store different types of packages other than the widely used ones like NuGet, npm, Maven, or Python packages.

To use the tool package for Linux and Mac, you could consider to use [HackPorts](http://buddhalabs.com/hackports/) and  [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/).

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer. NuGet marks things as 744 when it pulls on a Mac, so that's a viable alternative. I don't know why Universal packages are different.